# Form validation not working with tabs x in yii2

Tags: ajax, validation, widget, yii2

I am using kartik-v tabs x. My paage has 3 tabs[kartik v tabs x](http://demos.krajee.com/tabs-x#usage-ajax)

In each tab there is a form and a grid.

The form validation works in the first tab but not working in the inside tabs. The form is rendered using renderAjax. Also none of jquery work in the inside tabs.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Please add the code and describe what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the above problem.

When you use tabs and there are forms in it. Each form should have a separate id.

Then the default YII validation works for all tabs

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pjax;

inside the rendered view you have to add this:

```
Pjax::begin();
$form = ActiveForm::begin(
ActiveForm::end();
Pjax::end();
```

So u can use pjax for the validation. Let me now if it works.

Comment: I tried the above, I see that for the inside tabs, when I try pagination for the grid inside this tab its not working. it renders the page instead of loading it via ajax and layout breaks

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 tabs and two of them have both a form and grid and the third only has a grid. The validation and submission all will work if you use different ids for your forms and your js function names should be different.